# Are there any JDBC implementations for NoSql databases?

Tags: java, database, jdbc, nosql

I just wonder if there are any JDBC implementations (in some extent, as much as possible) for any NoSql DB (opensource or proprietary)?

How do you think, is it possible that this implementation will show as good performance as raw API of correspondent NoSql DB?

Which parts cannot be implemented (transactions? CallableStatements? etc)?

Comment: Why was this closed? This is a perfect valid question.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

SQL-based DBs have more in common than different. JDBC builds on those commonalities. If you take away SQL, most of the rationale for JDBC is gone! Also, NoSQL DBs have pretty widely varying APIs... there's hardly anything to capture under a common set of methods.

Short answer: No.

Comment: it took almost half a year to realize that you're probably right.

Comment: @Roman: Hehe! Thanks anyway for the late acknowledgement. :)

Answer (score 4):

Yes for MongoDB there are several lib available much like JDBC,JPA. 
use this [**link**](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Java+Language+Center) 
I did a test application and i found that performance of the MongoDB is much better than MySQL 
while performing bulk inserts and fetching large no of records.

If you are considering any NoSQL data store i would recommend MongoDB.

Comment: +1 The link I have been looking for! Everything I need to know about Mongo, thank you sir!

Comment: It is debatable how "like" JDBC (or JPA) they are, but the drivers you linked to are in fact not JDBC compliant.

Answer (score 3):

What SUN did those days was to create abstract specifications for all relational database systems so that Java developers can work with them all easily provided the providers create implementations. That is what JDBC is. An abstract front for relational Databases.

NoSQl is not Relational and there will need to exists a kind of a NoSQL Connectivity Framework probably led by Oracle so that all NoSQL database providers can implement freely and allow Java Developers access via a common ground.

Answer (score 0):

There is a experimental try on this regard please find https://github.com/erh/mongo-jdbc